# How to return an unknown amount of data from a parallel job? (C# Jobs + Burst)

Tags: unity, c#, jobs, unity-job-system, burst

Say we have a parallel job (implementing [`IJobParallelFor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.IJobParallelFor.html)) which requires a large array (>100,000 items) as an input to do some complicated processing. After said job is finished, I'd like to return a portion of those items that have passed certain checks.

Specifically, I'd like to check if >100,000 Vector3's satisfy a certain criteria. If they do, I'd like to add them to a list so that I can continue operating on that data in the main thread (or in other jobs).

The issue is that we can't use a NativeList to call .Add() because that data structure doesn't support parallel writing. It is also not viable to use a NativeArray because it requires its size to be initialized ahead of time, and we don't know how many items we are going to return.

What is a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like IJobParallelFilter might be helpful here, but I'm finding the documentation very lacking. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NativeQueue`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.collections@1.1/api/Unity.Collections.NativeQueue-1.html) for your results, then obtain a [`NativeQueue<T>.ParallelWriter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.collections@1.1/api/Unity.Collections.NativeQueue-1.ParallelWriter.html) for it using `results.AsParallelWriter()`. It exposes a method `Enqueue(T)` to add elements to the queue.

You can then later read from that queue by copying it to an array using `results.ToArray()` or by processing the queue using a `while(results.TryDequeue(out result)) {` loop.

The NativeList also offers a parallel writer, by the way, but that one [does not offer operations which exceed the initial capacity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.collections@1.1/api/Unity.Collections.NativeList-1.ParallelWriter.html).

Comment: I also just found the [`NativeStream`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.collections@1.1/api/Unity.Collections.NativeStream.html) which might also be an option, but seems more suitable for a scenario where the result-set is larger than the number of iterations of the IJobParallelFor, not smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `NativeArray<bool> IsValid` to indicate which items require some more processing.

Items can then be aggregated in one place (e.g. in another `IJob` in a loop); or the flag can be used in the followup method in the next job to quit early.

This has the advantage of fixed-size, low synchronization overhead. It requires a tiny bit more RAM. Cache locality is sometimes better, sometimes worse.